# reading filenames from a file and moving files from one location to other in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have one file which contains filenames.
I want read those filenames from that file and move them to particular location.

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{old=$0;new=/path/pathsub/;system("mv \""old"\" "new)}' your_file_with_file_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r filename; 
do
  mv "$filename" /DESTINATION/PATH/
done < input_filename
```

Comment: Hi above one is working fine but i am getting warning mesaage as
/informatica/ETD/PC9/scripts/kamil/Moving_flies/file1.txt: Hi: not found.
/informatica/ETD/PC9/scripts/kamil/Moving_flies/file2.txt: Hi: not found.
 /informatica/ETD/PC9/scripts/kamil/Moving_flies/file3.txt: Hi: not found.

Comment: @user955086 That means `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` do not exist on your system but you have them in your input_filename. So `mv` complains about it. You can ignore it and carry on.

Comment: can you tell me any command which won't display warnings ?

Comment: Just redirect stderr. Change `mv` line to: `mv "$filename" /DESTINATION/PATH/ 2>/dev/null`

Comment: can u help me on this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473732/attaching-more-than-2-files-in-mail-in-unix