# Attaching more than 2 files in mail in Unix

Tags: unix

I am having many files to be attached and send them via email.
I am running script to do so.
Can you help me with code ?

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? What script are you using? Can you provide the code? Errors output?

Comment: cat Mail_Report.txt ; uuencode file1.txt file1.txt file2.txt file2.txt

Comment: Old post I know but just wanted to note that earlier versions of mailx (including the one on RHEL5/OEL5/CentOS5) did not support the -a flag for attachments. The version of mutt on those did. As of RHEL6 and its derivatives the version of mailx included DOES support the -a flag.

Answer (score 15):

You can use option `-a` of `mailx` several times, for example:

```
$ mailx -s 'Few files attached' -a file1.txt -a file2.txt someone@some.com
```

You can also use `uuencode` like this:

```
$  ( cat Mail_Report.txt; uuencode file1.txt file1.txt ; uuencode file2.txt file2.txt ) | mailx -s "SUBJECT" someone@some.com
```

Comment: first option which you told is not working following is error
mailx: Not a recognized flag: a
Second option you told is fine but one 1 file is attached or file is not getting attached.

Comment: It works on my Linux box (OpenSuse 11). What is your system? BTW, you can always tar the files and attach the archive as one file.

Comment: "-A" is the correct parameter for attachments in most modern mailx utilities (including that from mailutils).  -a adds a header.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below code snippet

```
files_string="-a file_1 -a file_2 ... -a file_3"
sender_mail="xyz@mk.com"
receiver_mail="abc@mk.com"
IFS=" "
echo "body text " | mailx -s "subject1" $files_string -r $sender_mail $receiver_mail;
```

Comment: Please declare your code and think about formatting it.